# Multithreading Python: Thread Communication

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm using the `threading` module in Python and have read the tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm). My intended program flow is that I have 2 functions `foo()` and `bar()` and the following happens

1) `foo()` runs and collects some data stored in `data` then stops.

2) `bar()` then runs continuously using `data`.

3) After 2 minutes `foo()` runs again and updates `data` while `bar()` continues to run using the old version of `data`.

4) After the successful update `bar()` starts using the new version of data.

5) Loop back to (3)

Now I want to run these as separate threads and my issue lies in how does `foo()` tell `bar()` it has finished running and the new version of `data` is available?

I've read about `Queue` but couldn't see exactly how I would use it in this instance.

Comment: How does `bar` use the data? Does it keep using it over and over, or just once? If just once, then either the `Queue` or `Pipe` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how bar consumes the data. If bar has some natural point where it can choose to use existing or new data, it can read a queue filled by foo.

```
def foo(bar_q):
    while True:
        data = get_some_data()
        # copy or deepcopy if foo will be updating data instead of fetching new
        bar_q.put(copy.copy(data))
        time.sleep(120)

def bar(bar_q):
    # wait for the first data
    data = bar_q.get()
    bar_q.task_done()
    while True:
        process_some_data(data)
        try:
            # get new data if available
            data = bar_q.get_nowait()
            bar_q.task_done()
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass
```

Comment: Thanks, it took me a while to get my head around the threading but its working!